# "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Tags: c#, ms-access

when I click the btnCheckout, it will give me 
"No value given for one or more required parameters."

Does anyone know why?

```
protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string strPay = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].Text;
            string strDel = DropDownList2.Items[DropDownList2.SelectedIndex].Text;
            OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
            mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
                + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.accdb");
            string strStatus = "CheckedOut";
            int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];
            String strSqlUpdate = "UPDATE orderInfo SET orderPayMode = @Pay, "
                + "orderDelMode = @Del, orderStatus = @Status WHERE orderNo = " + intOrderNo;
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSqlUpdate, mDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pay", strPay);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Del", strDel);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", strStatus);
            mDB.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mDB.Close();
            Response.Redirect("OrderDetails.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Try executing your `mDB.Open()` *before* creating your `OleDbCommand` object. I've seen that fix some seemingly strange errors in other people's code.

Comment: Please don't edit the question away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or more of the paremeters are null. Check if strPay, strDel or strStatus is null or not. 
If any of them is null you can send empty string or SqlString.Null.

If some parameter value is null that parameter doesn't get added that's why this error.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pay", strPay==null?SqlString.Null:strPay);
```

Comment: Null? Null as in null in the database or in the ddl?

Comment: Object reference is null. e.g. strPay variable can be null

Comment: I don't think they are null. I had a previous project saved as backup and that strangely worked with the same codes.

Comment: why not make sure to rule out possibilities?

Comment: Well, its not about the database. For example you are getting "strPay" from DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].Text. You need to check if this statement is giving null.

Comment: I checked it again & it's not giving me null statements. What should be the next course of action then?

Comment: Did you check if "strPay" or "strBill" has any value or not by debugging?

Comment: All of them had value; their values went into the database sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what nhrobin is saying, consider changing your code to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pay", strPay ?? "");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Del", strDel ?? "");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", strStatus ?? "");
```

and that should help it succeed. However, a more striking question is this:

> What **should** we be doing when these values are `null`?

That's a question you're going to have to answer. If what I've provided is satisfactory then you're set.