# SQL INNER JOIN Syntax works on Access but not on VBA

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to import data from my Access database in a VBA form using a button and a gridview. I tested the code in Access and it worked, but for some reason it doesn't work when I try to implement it in VBA button. I get the error "No value given for one or more required parameters". Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong?

This is the code (I translated it to English, so maybe I forgot to modify something, but I repeat that it worked on Access):

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        Dim dataFile = "C:\Users\solov\Downloads\LibrarieV2.accdb"

        conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
        conn.Open()
        Dim q = "SELECT Customers.gender, Books.book_category, " & _
        " SUM(Details_sales.total_cost) AS TotalSumCategory " & _
        " FROM ((Customers INNER JOIN Sales ON Customers.customer_id = " & _
        " Sales.customer_id )INNER JOIN Details_sales ON Sales.sale_id = " & _
        " Details_sales.sale_id) INNER JOIN Books ON Details_sales.isbn = " & _
        " Books.isbn GROUP BY Customers.gender, Books.book_category, " & _
        " TotalSumCategory ORDER BY Books.book_category"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(q, conn)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(q, conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Dim ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Categories") ---> this is the chart that I will use to populate the grid 
        DataGridView1Form2.DataMember = "Categories"
        DataGridView1Form2.DataSource = ds
```

Comment: Your code is not VBA, but VB.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No value given for one or more required parameters."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066600/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Comment: The aggregate calc field TotalSumCategory does not need to be in GROUP BY clause but you say it works regardless. I don't see anything wrong with the SQL except SELECT statements in Access end with semi-colon. Might try adding that to the string.

Comment: @June7  Actually, Access SQL does not supports column aliases in the GROUP BY clause, so this is likely the cause of the error since Access will not recognize the column alias, so it will interpret it as a parameter (which in this case is without value).  If this exact statement "worked" in Access, I suppose it would generate a parameter prompt.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem for me. It was because of that TotalSumCategory alias in the group by. Thank you so much!